# Android AsyncTask running time difference between USB debugging and standadlone device

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a long running background task involving heavy computation and disk reads.

When my nexus 5 is connected to my laptop with usb debugging the total running time of the background task is approx. 7 minutes.

When I run it on the device alone, not connected, it can take up to 1 hour. Inspection of the logcat shows that it is being blocked for various intervals.

I assume this is partly due to scheduling so I tried to force the priority of the async task using andorid.os.Process, ensuring it is parallel using task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) and I have also tried using a Java Thread instead, however I get the same results.

Am I missing something about USB debugging and running an aynctask? If I start running my app on the phone alone, and then plug in the USB to view the logcat I may see that it had been blocked previously but it will then run back at normal speed. My processing is quite intensive but I need it to complete as quickly as possible. Is there a way to do this? I am currently testing using an IntentService instead but wanted to get some advice first.

So my questions are:

Is there a difference between usb debugging and running alone on the device in terms of scheduling as my async task is being blocked when running on device alone but not when it is run on the device with usb debugging?

Secondly, how can I ensure that my background task runs with minimal interruptions, or is there a better way to run a long compuational task, 7 minutes, off the main thread?

Comment: This is not an android issue.  This is an example of poor design.  Please ask a question about a lazyloader.

Comment: I am using a sort of lazy loader pattern to ensure I dont have unused objects hanging around. Everything on the heap is needed at that time, this is a complex image processing system that requires the long processing time. I managed to get this working using an intentservice but i still want to know why there was no scheduling problem when I have the phone plugged into my laptop. I dont see how your comment is helpful, please read the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this issue was down to the CPU going to sleep.

I have found that an Intentservice with a wakelock to keep the CPU on does the trick. I guess maybe when USB debugging is happening the CPU does not sleep?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe USB debugging should affect the speed of your background tasks. However, I know that you shouldn't do heavy, long running networking or computation using AsyncTasks. They aren't meant for that.

**As mentioned in the documentation**

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

Perhaps you could have a look at using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for long running operations. Services can be started from Activities and can communicate through Broadcast Receivers.

Comment: Thanks, I am implementing a service now and testing forcing the startForeground, but it seems I am having the same problem. When I have the USB connected I can view the logcat and my code is running in order each individual process taking 60ms with 6000 of them, around 7 mins to complete. When I start the app not connected, wait 7 minutes, then plug the USB in the logcat shows that the process has only run maybe 1000 times with long gaps between. I hope im missing some stupid here as I need this is run at 7 minutes not nearly 1 hour!

Comment: That's very strange, I'd be interested to see what you are doing in your code. Something funny is going on, I certainly haven't experienced that on my Nexus 5.

Comment: It's the same on a Galaxy S3. The code is simply a loop where an image is read in from the resources folder, then some processing is done on the image to form 81 new images, this is done 6000 times. Im watching it now with USB debugging each loop takes 60ms. When it is not connected there can be 20minute gaps between the end and start of a loop?! There must be something to do with blocking, scheduling, foreground running that Im hoping someone on here has knowledge of.